# Nullpointerexception when trying to do a simple operation

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I have been writing a part of code this entire evening and now I am stuck at a nullpointerexception I cannot get away.

the code is supposed to read everything from a file in a format like this:
The train-line in question
Every station located on that train-line

and save this into objects in a hashmap.

I don't really know for sure if it really does save the objects, but I did check for specific keys (the station's names are the keys in the station-map) and they existed, so something must be right.

The part of code where it happens, is the second line after the if-statement:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < fraLinjeListe.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tilLinjeListe.size(); j++) {
            if(fra.linjeList.get(i).equals(til.linjeList.get(j))){
                Linje aktuellLinje=linjerMap.get(fra.linjeList.get(i));
                tilStasjonsNummer=aktuellLinje.stasjonsNummer(til);
                fraStasjonsNummer=aktuellLinje.stasjonsNummer(fra);
                retning=tilStasjonsNummer-fraStasjonsNummer;
                endeStasjonsNavn=aktuellLinje.endestasjon(retning);
                System.out.println("Ta T-bane linje " + aktuellLinje.linjeNummer + " fra " + startStasjon + " til " + sluttStasjon + " i retning " + endeStasjonsNavn + ". Estimert reisetid: " + tid);             
            }   
        }
    }
```

The nullpointer:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
    at Planlegger.beregnRuter(oblig5.java:130)
    at Planlegger.tilStasjon(oblig5.java:104)
    at Planlegger.fraStasjon(oblig5.java:88)
    at Planlegger.lesFraTil(oblig5.java:77)
    at Planlegger.lesFil(oblig5.java:73)
    at Oblig5.main(oblig5.java:9)
```

The rest of the code:

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Oblig5{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Planlegger starten=new Planlegger();
    starten.lesFil();

    }
}
class Planlegger{

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    HashMap<String, Linje> linjerMap=new HashMap<String, Linje>();
    HashMap<String, Stasjon> stasjonerMap=new HashMap<String, Stasjon>();

    void lesFil(){

        Linje linjer;
        Stasjon stasjoner;
        String linjeLest="";
        String aktuellLinje="";
        String linjeNummer="";
        char[] linjeNummerA;
        int linjeNummerInt=0;

        try{
            Scanner innFil=new Scanner(new File("Rutetabell.txt"));

            while(innFil.hasNextLine()){

                linjeLest=innFil.nextLine().toLowerCase();

                if(linjeLest.contains("linje")){
                    /* System.out.println("TESTILINJE"); */
                    //Bruker en string for linjenummeret her for å lette bruken av nummeret som key i HashMapen. 

                    linjeNummerInt=Integer.parseInt(linjeLest.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
                    // linjeNummerA[0]=linjeLest.split("*linje* ").charAt(0);
                    // linjeNummer=linjeNummer[0];
                    linjeNummer=String.valueOf(linjeNummerInt);
                    linjer=new Linje(linjeNummer);
                    aktuellLinje=linjeNummer;
                    linjerMap.put(linjeNummer, linjer); 

                }else{
/*                  System.out.println("TESTISTASJON"); */
                    //Dersom ikke objektet finnes i hashmapen for stasjoner allerede, så lages objektet og lagres i HashMapen. 
                    if(!stasjonerMap.containsKey(linjeLest)){
                        stasjonerMap.put(linjeLest, new Stasjon(linjeLest));
                    }
                    //Her henter jeg ut objektet vi lager over, og om det ikke lages fordi det allerede eksisterer så hentes det ut uansett.
                    stasjoner=stasjonerMap.get(linjeLest);
                    //Her brukes objektinformasjonen over til å registrere stasjonen i objektet
                    linjer=linjerMap.get(aktuellLinje);
                    linjer.registrerStasjoner(linjeLest, stasjoner);
                    stasjoner.registrerNyLinje(aktuellLinje, linjer);
                }       
            }
            innFil.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
/*      System.out.println("Test");
        String sjekkHashmap=input.nextLine();
        if(stasjonerMap.containsKey(sjekkHashmap)){
            System.out.println("Det funker!");
        } */

        lesFraTil();
    }

    void lesFraTil(){
        fraStasjon();
    }

    void fraStasjon(){

        boolean sjekkStasjon=true;
        while(sjekkStasjon){
            System.out.println("Vennligst tast inn fra-stasjonen: ");
            String startStasjon=input.next().toLowerCase();
            if(stasjonerMap.containsKey(startStasjon)){
                sjekkStasjon=false;
                tilStasjon(startStasjon);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Stasjon ikke funnet.");
                sjekkStasjon=true;
            }
        }
    }

    void tilStasjon(String startStasjon){

        boolean sjekkStasjon=true;
        while(sjekkStasjon){
            System.out.println("Vennligst tast inn til-stasjonen: ");
            String sluttStasjon=input.next().toLowerCase();
            if(stasjonerMap.containsKey(sluttStasjon)){
                sjekkStasjon=false;
                beregnRuter(startStasjon, sluttStasjon);
            }else{  
                System.out.println("Stasjon ikke funnet.");
                sjekkStasjon=true;
            }
        }
    }

    void beregnRuter(String startStasjon, String sluttStasjon){

        Stasjon til=stasjonerMap.get(startStasjon);
        Stasjon fra=stasjonerMap.get(sluttStasjon);
        ArrayList<Linje> fraLinjeListe=new ArrayList<Linje>(fra.linjeList);
        ArrayList<Linje> tilLinjeListe=new ArrayList<Linje>(til.linjeList);
        int tilStasjonsNummer, fraStasjonsNummer;
        int retning;
        double tid= 0.0;
        String endeStasjonsNavn;

        tilStasjonsNummer=0;
        fraStasjonsNummer=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < fraLinjeListe.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tilLinjeListe.size(); j++) {
                if(fra.linjeList.get(i).equals(til.linjeList.get(j))){
                    Linje aktuellLinje=linjerMap.get(fra.linjeList.get(i));
                    tilStasjonsNummer=aktuellLinje.stasjonsNummer(til);
                    fraStasjonsNummer=aktuellLinje.stasjonsNummer(fra);
                    retning=tilStasjonsNummer-fraStasjonsNummer;
                    endeStasjonsNavn=aktuellLinje.endestasjon(retning);
                    System.out.println("Ta T-bane linje " + aktuellLinje.linjeNummer + " fra " + startStasjon + " til " + sluttStasjon + " i retning " + endeStasjonsNavn + ". Estimert reisetid: " + tid);             
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}

class Linje{
    String linjeNummer="";
    HashMap<String, Stasjon> linjeStasjoner=new HashMap<String, Stasjon>();
    int antallStasjoner=0;
    int type=0;
    ArrayList<Stasjon> stasjonsList=new ArrayList<Stasjon>();

    Linje(String linjeNummer){
        this.linjeNummer=linjeNummer;
        int linjeNummerInt=Integer.parseInt(linjeNummer);
        if (linjeNummerInt < 10 ){
            type=0;
        }else{
            type=1;
        }
    }

    void registrerStasjoner(String linjeLest, Stasjon stasjon){
        linjeStasjoner.put(linjeLest, stasjon);
        stasjonsList.add(stasjon);
        antallStasjoner++;
    }

    int antall=stasjonsList.size();

    boolean inneholder(Stasjon stasjon){
        boolean sannhetsSjekk=true;
        if(stasjonsList.contains(stasjon)){
            sannhetsSjekk=true;
        }else{
            sannhetsSjekk=false;
        }
        return sannhetsSjekk;
    }

    String endestasjon(int retning) {   
        String endestasjonen;
        if (retning > 0) {
            endestasjonen=stasjonsList.get(0).stasjonNavn;
            return endestasjonen;
        }else{
            endestasjonen=stasjonsList.get(antall-1).stasjonNavn;
            return endestasjonen;
        }
    }

    int stasjonsNummer (Stasjon s) {

        int selveNummeret=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < stasjonsList.size(); i++) {
            if (stasjonsList.get(i) == s) {
                selveNummeret=i+1;
            }
        }
        return selveNummeret;   
    }
}   

class Stasjon{
    String stasjonNavn;
    Linje linje;
    HashMap <String, Linje> stasjonsLinjer=new HashMap<String, Linje>();
    ArrayList<Linje> linjeList=new ArrayList<Linje>();
    int teller=0;

    Stasjon(String linjeLest){
    this.stasjonNavn=linjeLest;
    }

    void registrerNyLinje(String aktuellLinje, Linje linje){
    stasjonsLinjer.put(aktuellLinje, linje);
    linjeList.add(linje);
    teller++;
    }
}

class Overgang{

        Linje l1, l2;
        Stasjon fra,til,bytte;
        Planlegger planlegger;




}
```

Comment: Holy crap, reading code in Norwegian is a nightmare. That's insane.

Comment: Hahaha, I guess I agree a little :P

Comment: It could serve as an example for some co-workers, who think it is ok to write their code in their own language rather than in english. ;-)

Comment: It would appear that aktuellLinje is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a null pointer in

```
tilStasjonsNummer=aktuellLinje.stasjonsNummer(til);
```

It means that `aktuellLinje` is `null`.

Most likely `linjerMap` is not able to get the value corresponding to the key  `fra.linjeList.get(i)` in the following statement.

```
Linje aktuellLinje=linjerMap.get(fra.linjeList.get(i));
```

It could be that

- The map is empty
  This can be confirmed by logging the size of the map, and doing a null check/empty check on the map (`linjerMap!= null && !linjerMap.isEmpty()`)
- The map does not have the correct object 
  This can be confirmed by checking if the map contains the element (`linjerMap.containsKey(fra.linjeList.get(i))`) or by iterating through the map, to confirm the contents:

  ```
  for(Map.Entry entry : linjerMap) 
  {
      System.out.println(linjerMap.getKey() + " ," +linjerMap.getValue() );
  }
  ```

Comment: So what you're saying is taht in my hashmaps, there are nothing saved?

Comment: That is a possibility. Other possibilities are that the map does not contain the object you are looking for or the object does not implement equals/hashcode correctly. Why this is happening can be confirmed by debugging the code.

Comment: Do note that if there is no value mapped to the key (or the key isn't in the map), it will always return `null`, so you could either null check or figure out why the value you're looking for isn't in there.

Comment: Okay. But if I want to null check the content of a object in a hashmap, should I do something like this then?

if(stasjonerMap.get(sjekkHashmap)==null)

Comment: @Makri just check if the result you got is null, no need to check then assign. if it isn't null, then continue with the rest of the code.

Comment: Okay, but that part above didn't hint to it being null. Inside the if-statement I placed a printline, but it didn't print so shouldn't that mean there is an object there?

@ Nivas:
I tried the null check/empty check on the map, and by my understanding, if I placed your statement in an if-sentence, it shouldn't print if the map is empty? Well, it did print :O 
Can it be the making of the objects itself that is wrong? So the variables it tries to get the value from isn't existing?

Answer (score 0):

FIGURED IT OUT! 
The problem was that my line

`Linje aktuellLinje=linjerMap.get(fra.linjeList.get(i));`

Was getting the object itself, and then tried to use the object as a key to find in the hashmap, giving the nullpointer. When I added .linjeNummer at the end, it got the name of the train-line, which is also the keys, and used that one. It now works.